Invalid argument error when passing 2d array into a function
Creating a machine learning algorithm in HLS and getting this error when passing 2d array into the dot product function.
void matMul (float** weights, float* input_vec, int input_size, float* output_vec, int output_size)
{
}

float weights[10][64] = {{...}, {...}, ...};
float input[64];
float output[10];

matMul (weights, input, 64, output, 10);

The error reads Invalid arguments 'Candidates are: void matMul(float * *, float *, int, float *, int)' despite the data types matching. I tried removing the 2d array from the function and call and no errors popped up, so the issue is with the 2d array.
Changing the function to:
void matMul (float weights[][64], float* input_vec, int input_size, float* output_vec, int output_size)

for some reason fixes the issue, only when I filled in a 64 into the second bracket. But I'm using this function for 3 calls with different values so I can't hard code this.
Any idea how to fix this?

Short answer: no, you can't. Array to pointer decay will only decay one level, so you get a pointer to array of 64 floats.

You could take the arrays by refrence instead: void matMul(float (&weights)[10][64], float (&input_vec)[64], float (&output_vec)[10]) { ... } and then calling your function with matMul(weights, input, output); - or more generic template<size_t Y, size_t X> void matMul(float (&weights)[Y][X], float (&input_vec)[X], float (&output_vec)[Y]) { ... }
